# How many threads used by Async.Parallel

Tags: f#

Example this code:

```
let b id = 
    async {
        printfn "running %A \n" id
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        printfn "finish %A \n" id
    }
let works = [1..100]
works |> Seq.map b|> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

how many threads will be used ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is; we can't know. And why would we want to?

Also, it's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking whether b will be run on a single thread from start to end? For this example the answer is yes, but a slight change could turn the answer into a no. Are you asking how many threads will be used in total? By ID or by runs? How many will run simultaneously?

It is often better just to think in terms of asyncs rather than threads, since threads are just resources used behind the scenes by asyncs.

Some more info.

There will be a thread pool that is used to run the asyncs, and the size of that thread pool is usually the number of processors. On my machine, I have 8 processors with hyperthreading, so then I guess there will be 16 threads in the thread pool.

The code in the Q produces a quite messy output, since printfn does not write atomically to the console. In order to see line by line output, I will use Console.WriteLine, which will write lines atomically.

```
open System

let t: bool[] = Array.zeroCreate 10000

let b id =
    async {
        let threadId = Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        t.[threadId] <- true
        Console.WriteLine $@"running {id} on {threadId}"
        Threading.Thread.Sleep 2000
        Console.WriteLine $@"finish {id} on {threadId}"
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    Console.WriteLine "Start"
    [1..100]
    |> Seq.map b
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> ignore
    Console.WriteLine "Done"
    let n = t |> Array.filter id |> Array.length
    Console.WriteLine $@"n = {n}"
    Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0
```

So here we keep track of which threads are used overall.

It turns out that the number of threads used varies from 19 to 23 on my machine, and I bet it can be lower and higher. But why isn't the number 16 on my machine? I suspect the reason for this higher than expected number is that the asyncs use Threading.Thread.Sleep instead of Async.Sleep. When a thread from the thread pool turns out to be long running, then soon a new thread must be allocated in its stead so that the corresponding processor can still be used effectively by the thread pool. If the length of the sleep is increased, then the number of threads used overall go up. If I try with Threading.Thread.Sleep 100_000, then 100 threads are used.

In production, use Async.Sleep instead for actually sleeping an async for a while, so that thread pool threads are not blocked, but returned to the thread pool so that they can do other work instead of just doing a blocked sleep for a long time. When I do that here, only 33 threads are used. But 33 still seems high. Do I still have a problem? I don't think so. Let's explore some more to see why.

There is an overload of Async.Parallel which can be used to specify the degree of parallelism. Let's see what happens.

```
open System

let t: bool[] = Array.zeroCreate 10000

let b id =
    async {
        let threadId = Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        t.[threadId] <- true
        Console.WriteLine $@"running {id} on {threadId}"
        // Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        do! Async.Sleep 2000
        let threadId2 = Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        t.[threadId2] <- true
        Console.WriteLine $@"finish {id} on {threadId2}"
        if threadId <> threadId2 then Console.WriteLine "NOT THE SAME THREAD!"
    }

let asyncParallel x y = Async.Parallel (y, x)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    Console.WriteLine "Start"
    [1..100]
    |> Seq.map b
    |> asyncParallel 3
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> ignore
    Console.WriteLine "Done"
    let n = t |> Array.filter id |> Array.length
    Console.WriteLine $@"n = {n}"
    Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0
```

When I run this, I usually get n = 6, but I've also gotten 5. Why does it tend towards 6, but not always be exactly 6? And why isn't it 3?

If the nasty Threading.Thread.Sleep is used instead of Async.Sleep, then n will tend towards 3.

If one more Async.Sleep is inserted into b, so that there are two, will then n tend towards 9? Surprisingly, no! It's still at 6.

So far it looks like use of one or more bang - the do! in our case - will cause use of two threads per b running in total, instead of only one. Not sure why, but of course it doesn't mean two threads are used simultaneously by one run of b, but rather in sequence, before and after the Async.Sleep. (Can also sometimes happen to be the same thread that continues the work, which can explain why I got 5 rather than 6 one time.)

Now we can guess more easily as to why 33 threads was used when Threading.Thread.Sleep 100_000 was replaced with Async.Sleep 100_000. It's just one more than 32, which is 2 * 16, and 16 is the expected number of threads in the thread pool. When Async.Sleep 500_000 is used, the number of threads involved is still only 33 on my machine.

We haven't really reached any conclusions with the experiments, but we've gotten some insight into how things work.

Comment: Bro. A lot to unpack here. Thanks